# spring-cloud config runs ok locally but on docker it shows Cannot clone or checkout repository

Tags: docker, docker-compose, spring-cloud-config

I'm running Spring Cloud Config Server OK locally, but I want to try docker for the project . and the same code got some errors on docker !

As the config server will pull configs from git , when we are in docker 
i found the log says :

> Cannot clone or checkout repository] with root cause
>   org.eclipse.jgit.errors.CheckoutConflictException: Checkout conflict with files:

I try to delete all the images and clear docker cache and rebuild and re run it , at the end same error shows

```
spring:
    application:
        name: ace-config
    profiles:
        active: dev
    cloud:
      config:
        server:
          git:
            uri: https://gitlab.com/xxx/myproj.git
            searchPaths: config
            username: xxx
            password: xxx
            default-label: develop
```

and this is my dockerfile

```
FROM livingobjects/jre8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD ./target/ace-config.jar app.jar
RUN rm -rf  /tmp/*
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
```

and this is my docker-compose.yml

```
ace-config:
    build: ./ace-config
    image: mipay/ace-config:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
    - ace-center
    command: >
      bash -c "
      while ! (nc -z unipay 8761);
      do sleep 5;
      echo 'Waiting for config and center services to start-up...';
      done;
      java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar
      "
    ports:
    - "8750:8750"
    extra_hosts:
    - "unipay2:172.31.68.159"
    - "unipay:172.31.68.159"
    - "mipay:172.31.68.159"
    volumes:
    - /opt/logs/:/opt/logs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible you came across this issue:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/407

But actually, Spring Cloud Config Server acknowledges that the local copy in the config server can get dirty

> (for example, folder content changes by an OS process)

For this, a `force-pull` property can be set to true as [documented here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_force_pull_in_git_repositories).

Also, as system temporary directory (e.g. /tmp/) can be modified by OS processes, you can specify exactly where you want to put the checked out repository using `spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir` as [documented here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_version_control_backend_filesystem_use).

Can you try and see if these helps?

Comment: thanks , I add these three to my config:
            clone-on-start: true
            strict-host-key-checking: false
            force-pull: true
and also I mount a path to docker path which saving the local cache for git config .
now it works well